# Macos sorts file randomly (at least it seems so to me)

Tags: finder, macos, sort

I checked other questions, checked Apple forums - the only thing I could find is `Sort by / Arrange by` but in my case none of their combinations helps me to get plain "by name" option, currently I can't even find any logic in how it sorts the files:
[image: macos sorting issue]

Any help is much appreciated. I'm on macOS 10.12.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic is simply that the file names you're looking at are sorted numerically. Finder takes the file names and note that they start with a number - everything up to first non-number character is then sorted numerically.

I.e. from your example 9873613 < 13480567 < 39758380 < 46432537 < 81233033.

Note that some files have 7 digits, others have 8 digits.

In general Finder's sorting takes sequences of numeric digits and treat them as a single number to be sorted. Non-numeric parts are sorted alphabetically like you would expect. This system of collation is called ["natural sorting"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_sort_order).

Comment: iirc, this is known as "rational sorting" as opposed to the complete mess that would result from sorting as  1, 10, 11, 2, 20, 3, 4...

Comment: Programmers call it "natural sorting". I haven't heard "rational sorting" been used to describe that before.

Comment: ah, OK. I wasn't aware it had a coder's definition. I've seen the term 'rational' used in other contexts.

Comment: wow @jksoegaard, ok, that makes sense, I never thought it would treat filenames as anything except strings. it still leaves lots of open questions like how it would treat string starting with a number (like "5zxcv") or would a valid hex number be a string or a number ("DEADBEE"). but most important one is - whether it possible to disable it at all and treat all like strings according to their position in char table.